# Extract date part from a file path string

Tags: ruby, string, split

I have a string that looks like this: `log/archive/2016-12-21.zip`, and I need to extract the date part.

So far I have tried these solutions:

```
1) ["log/archive/2016-12-21.zip"].map{|i|i[/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/]}.first 
2) "log/archive/2016-12-21.zip".to_date
3) "log/archive/2016-12-21.zip".split("/").last.split(".").first
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: if the dot should always comes only at the last then you may try this `"log/archive/2016-12-21.zip".split(/[\/.]/)[-2]`

Comment: Yes dot will always come at last

Comment: Even it isn't the easiest solution, i would allways go with a regex ( \/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\.zip ). The reason is, that you can test it with a match, and you will surely detect if the structure of the string changes. I don't know how number 2 behaves, but i wouldn't go with number 3, since it can evaluate strings with no dates at all...

Answer (score 4):

You can use `File.basename` passing the extension:

```
File.basename("log/archive/2016-12-21.zip", ".zip")
# => "2016-12-21"
```

If you want the value to be a `Date`, simply use `Date.parse` to convert the string into a `Date.

```
require 'date'
Date.parse(File.basename("log/archive/2016-12-21.zip", ".zip"))
```

Comment: If the the strings are from a directory read, this would be a really good solution. But my question out of interest, what will happen if there is no valid date in the file name ? for example "log/archive/12-21.zip"

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo in that case, instead of passing the value directly to `Date.parse` you will have to handle the parsing on your own and compose a date.

Comment: yeah but do you know the behaviour of ruby in this case, will it fail and give an exception ? or will it be something like 1970-12-21 ?

Comment: it is sure that date will be in proper format always

Comment: First: `File.basename` acts on a string - it doesn't matter if the string was generated from another `File` action. So it is irrelevant whether the strings were obtained from a directory read - it is the format of the string that is relevant

Comment: Second: `Date.parse '12-21'` returns a date matching the 12th of the current month. (on my system anyway) - try it at a 'irb' prompt - remember to `require date` first.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'date'

def pull_dates(str)
  str.split(/[\/.]/).map { |s| Date.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d') rescue nil }.compact
end

pull_dates "log/archive/2016-12-21.zip"
  #=> [#<Date: 2016-12-21 ((2457744j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]
pull_dates "log/2016-12-21/archive.zip"
  #=> [#<Date: 2016-12-21 ((2457744j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]
pull_dates "log/2016-12-21/2016-12-22.zip"
  #=> [#<Date: 2016-12-21 ((2457744j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #    #<Date: 2016-12-22 ((2457745j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>] 
pull_dates "log/2016-12-21/2016-12-32.zip"
  #=> [#<Date: 2016-12-21 ((2457744j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]
pull_dates "log/archive/2016A-12-21.zip"
  #=> []
pull_dates "log/archive/2016/12/21.zip"
  #=> []
```

If you just want the date string, rather than the date object, change the method as follows.

```
def pull_dates(str)
  str.split(/[\/.]/).
      each_with_object([]) { |s,a|
        a << s if (Date.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d') rescue nil)}
end

pull_dates "log/archive/2016-12-21.zip"
  #=> ["2016-12-21"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex should cover most cases. It allows an optional non-digit between year, month and day :

```
require 'date'

def extract_date(filename)
  if filename =~ /((?:19|20)\d{2})\D?(\d{2})\D?(\d{2})/ then
    year, month, day = $1.to_i, $2.to_i, $3.to_i
    # Do something with year, month, day, or just leave it like this to return an array : [2016, 12, 21]
    # Date.new(year, month, day)
  end
end

p extract_date("log/archive/2016-12-21.zip")
p extract_date("log/archive/2016.12.21.zip")
p extract_date("log/archive/2016:12:21.zip")
p extract_date("log/archive/2016_12_21.zip")
p extract_date("log/archive/20161221.zip")
p extract_date("log/archive/2016/12/21.zip")
p extract_date("log/archive/2016/12/21")
#=> Every example returns [2016, 12, 21]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
"log/archive/2016-12-21.zip".scan(/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/).pop
=> "2016-12-21"
```

If the date format is invalid, it will return nil.

Example:-

```
"log/archive/20-12-21.zip".scan(/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/).pop
             ^^
=> nil
```

Hope it helps.